# "Encoding historical names" vs canonical names, say as charsetName argument of InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, utf-8, io, canonical-name

*Canonical names of encodings* is clear - here is the [official list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html): we have *Canonical Names for `java.nio` API* and *Canonical Names for `java.io` API and `java.lang` API*.

1) But what is the list of **historical encoding** names?

`OuputStreamWriter` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#getEncoding--) for `getEncoding()`:

> If the encoding has an historical name then that name is returned; otherwise the encoding's canonical name is returned.
>
> If this instance was created with the *OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream,
>   String)* constructor **then the returned name**, being unique for the
>   encoding, **may differ from the name passed to the constructor**.

`Charset` [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

> Some charsets have an historical name that is defined for
>   compatibility with previous versions of the Java platform. A charset's
>   historical name is either its canonical name *or one of its aliases*.
>   The historical name is returned by the getEncoding() methods of the
>   InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter classes.

2) *Canonical names of encodings* [official list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) states that for `java.io` canonical name "UTF8" shall be used, while "UTF-8" is a canoical name for the new `java.nio`.

But InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter does accept "UTF-8" argument!

```
try {
    FileOutputStream stream1 = new FileOutputStream("d:\\file.txt");
    OutputStreamWriter writer1 = new OutputStreamWriter(stream1, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(writer1.getEncoding());
    writer1.close();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    System.out.println("wrong encoding detected"); // never triggered
}
```

It seems "UTF-8" is recognized fine, no `UnsupportedEncodingException` fired!

P.S. I think that any API (even non-NIO) now (SE8) can accept NIO-style, and java.lang/java.io style is called historical. It seems true at least  for InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter.

Does my proposition hold true?

Comment: An example for a `Charset` with a historical name is `MS1252`. It's historical name is "Cp1252" while the current name is "windows-1252".

``public class sun.nio.cs.MS1252 extends java.nio.charset.Charset implements sun.nio.cs.HistoricallyNamedCharset``

Comment: This example supports this idea: "java.lang/java.io style is called historical". Cp1252 is java.io style, and windows-1252 is java.nio style as per Oracle table above.

Comment: Yeah, after checking some Charsets it seems the historical names are  the "Cp" ones or the ones with underscore.

In Java 8 they have seemingly merged those all together for acceptance, as that is how I interpret the third column:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html